# How to set day of the week in Bulgarian language

Tags: php, date

I have to show tomorrow's day of the week in Bulgarian.
It is shown in English, how do I set it in Bulgarian?

```
<?php
 $now= new DateTime('now');
 $date=$now->modify('+1 day');                    

 echo $date->format('l');
          //prints Saturday
```

I did this with an array of Bulgarian names of days and it works, but is there a way to do it with `setlocale` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime `format` doesnt support locales, you have to convert to timestamp to use `strftime`

Use LC_TIME in `setlocale` only to change the settings for time related formats

```
<?php
$now= new DateTime('now');
$date=$now->modify('+1 day');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'bg');
echo strftime("%A", date_timestamp_get($date));
```

Comment: You have two options, try to add UTF-8 to the locale in this way `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'bg.UTF-8');` or use utf8_encode when printing `echo utf8_encode(strftime("%A", date_timestamp_get($date)));`

Comment: First way, it prints Saturday, second way it prints something but it is not in utf8. It's not in cyrillic.

Comment: May be late with this comment, but using iconv may resolve the issue with ???
iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", strftime("%A, %d %B %Y", date_timestamp_get($date)))